# AttributeError: set_default_verify_paths

Tags: python, python-requests

when I make a GET call using requests module I get this error `AttributeError: set_default_verify_paths`. I am using python 2.6.9 version. when I use `cURL` command, I get the proper output. Its just not happening in python program. Am I missing any configuration `setting/ package`.

here is the traceback:

```
 File "<string>", line 1, in <module>

  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/requests-2.7.0-py2.6.egg/requests/api.py", line 69, in get

     return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)

   File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/requests-2.7.0-py2.6.egg/requests/api.py", line 50, in request

    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/requests-2.7.0-py2.6.egg/requests/sessions.py", line 465, in request
     resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/requests-2.7.0-py2.6.egg/requests/sessions.py", line 573, in send
     r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)

  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/requests-2.7.0-py2.6.egg/requests/adapters.py", line 370, in send
   timeout=timeout

  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/requests-2.7.0-py2.6.egg/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 544, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)

  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/requests-2.7.0-py2.6.egg/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 341, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)

  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/requests-2.7.0-py2.6.egg/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 761, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()

  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/requests-2.7.0-py2.6.egg/requests/packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 238, in connect
    ssl_version=resolved_ssl_version)

  File "/usr/local/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/requests-2.7.0-py2.6.egg/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 269, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ctx.set_default_verify_paths()

AttributeError: set_default_verify_paths
```

Comment: you did not provide ANY of your code.

Comment: python -c 'import requests;requests.packag                                                                                        es.urllib3.disable_warnings();r=requests.get("<URL>,verify=False);print r.text'